# How to use Axis.IntervalAutoMode?

Tags: c#, .net

I need a Y axis with exactly five intervals. My code is like so

```
axisY.Interval = ((axisY.Maximum - axisY.Minimum) / 5);
```

I encounter the following bug:

[image]

It sometimes displays one less interval label. Also notice that when it doesn't display the label, the alignment is off because it shifts the entire graph up a little bit (it occupies the space of the missing label).

Is there a way I can use the `IntervalAutoMode` property to ensure it displays the correct number of interval labels?